# Topology REST API of OpenDayLight not working

Tags: rest, opendaylight

Guys am newbie to SDN and Open Day Light . Currently am exploring possibilities with REST api exposed by ODL . I have created a topology with 3 host and 1 switch as discussed in the link http://sdnhub.org/tutorials/opendaylight/ .
Now when i see the topology info of the default container via REST api like <>

```
http://localhost:8080/controller/nb/v2/topology/default
```

is see just this tag  in the page and nothing other than that .

What am i doing wrong here ? Am i missing something ? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Have you made sure that your remote controller is up and running?
You could also run the mininet command by providing the remote controller's ip address and port no at which it is listening.
Ex: sudo mn --topo single,3 --mac --switch ovsk --controller remote,ip=x.x.x.x,port=6633

Comment: Thanks for the response #shr 
I am very sure that remote controller is up and running , bcoz i could access all the REST api other than topology such as statistics, flowcontrol ....